# Ruby Custom Sorting

Tags: ruby, sorting, enumerable

I have got following array in Ruby.

```
arr = [
[13.0, ["mango", "banana", "jackfruit"]], 
[10.0, ["mango", "Milk", "Cofee"]], 
[4.0, ["mango"]]
[5.0, ["jackfruit"]], 
[6.0, ["mango", "banana"]], 
[5.0, ["mango", "banana"]], 
[10.0, ["banana", "jackfruit"]], 
[5.0, ["banana"]], 
]
```

I want the result to be sorted by following rules:

1. Sort by the Fruit arrays length first(Some how group by)
2. Sort by their price in lower - Higher Order.

Expected output:

```
[
[10.0, ["mango", "Milk", "Cofee"]], 
[13.0, ["mango", "banana", "jackfruit"]], 

[5.0, ["mango", "banana"]], 
[6.0, ["mango", "banana"]], 
[10.0, ["banana", "jackfruit"]], 

[4.0, ["mango"]]
[5.0, ["jackfruit"]], 
[5.0, ["banana"]], 
]
```

Explanation: First categories the the elements by the fruit arrays length then on each set perform sorting based upon their price(low-high).

I tried following codes, but it's not giving desired result!

```
arr.group_by{|x| x[1].length }.sort_by{|x| x[0]}.map{|x| x[1]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for an overly clever comparator here, you're sorting by numbers so simple negation can reverse the sorting and [`sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) can take care of the rest. For example:

```
arr.sort_by { |e| [-e.last.length, e.first] }
```

or if you prefer numeric indexes:

```
arr.sort_by { |e| [-e[1].length, e[0]] }
```

will give you:

```
[
  [10.0, ["mango", "Milk", "Cofee"]],
  [13.0, ["mango", "banana", "jackfruit"]],
  [ 5.0, ["mango", "banana"]],
  [ 6.0, ["mango", "banana"]],
  [10.0, ["banana", "jackfruit"]],
  [ 4.0, ["mango"]],
  [ 5.0, ["jackfruit"]],
  [ 5.0, ["banana"]]
]
```

as desired. [`Array#<=>`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) compares element by element so `sort_by` with a block that yields an array is quite common.

You might want to add more conditions to your comparisons though, what you have won't guarantee what order `[11.0, ['a', 'b', 'c']]` and `[11.0, ['x', 'y', 'z']]` will appear in.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do any special grouping.

```
arr.sort {|a, b| (b[1].length <=> a[1].length) * 10 + (a[0] <=> b[0]) }
```

Results in:

```
[
  [10.0, ["mango", "Milk", "Cofee"]],
  [13.0, ["mango", "banana", "jackfruit"]],
  [5.0, ["mango", "banana"]],
  [6.0, ["mango", "banana"]],
  [10.0, ["banana", "jackfruit"]],
  [4.0, ["mango"]],
  [5.0, ["jackfruit"]],
  [5.0, ["banana"]]
]
```

`#sort` passes yields values to compare. `<=>` returns -1, 0, or 1, depending on how they compare, so since you want to prioritize length over price, each item can have a "sort weight" of (length comparison * 10) + (price comparison).